# Animation function in class called from thread not working

Tags: python, qt5, pyside2

I have a qt5 ui file which I'm loadin through a class with fade in / fade out functions:

```
class LoadingScreen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingScreen, self).__init__()
        loader = QUiLoader()
        file = QFile("loading_screen.ui")
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        global loading_screen
        loading_screen = loader.load(file, self)
        file.close()
        self.initUI()

    def fadeIN(self):
        self.fade_in = QPropertyAnimation(self,"windowOpacity")
        self.fade_in.setDuration(500)
        self.fade_in.setStartValue(0.0)
        self.fade_in.setEndValue(1.0)
        self.fade_in.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InBack)
        self.fade_in.start()
        self.show()

    def fadeOUT(self):
        self.fade_out = QPropertyAnimation(self,"windowOpacity")
        self.fade_out.setDuration(500)
        self.fade_out.setStartValue(1.0)
        self.fade_out.setEndValue(0.0)
        self.fade_out.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutBack)
        self.fade_out.start()
```

I'm loading it with:

```
global loading_screen_window
loading_screen_window = LoadingScreen()
```

Then I start a thread which is doing some stuff like reading config:

```
config_thread = config(1,"config",1)
config_thread.start()
```

Works fine, at a certain point at the thread I want to call the fade out function of my LoadingScreen() class. The function gets executed but the animation won't work? What am I doing wrong? Calling the fade out function form somewhere else works, but not inside my thread.

I'm using Python 2.7, Qt5 and PySide2.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Why do you want to use the animation from another thread? What advantage would it have? A basic rule of Qt is that the GUI is only due and can be updated from the main thread. Q*Animation are specialized classes to run on the main thread without blocking them so I see no need, basics to run from another thread.

Comment: the thread im using is checking a config file, when somethings missing the loading screen should be faded out and another window in which the user can enter something should be displayed. this is why i want to use it from another thread

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

```
class LoadingScreen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingScreen, self).__init__()
        loader = QUiLoader()
        file = QFile("loading_screen.ui")
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        global loading_screen
        loading_screen = loader.load(file, self)
        file.close()
        self.initUI()

        #Config Thread starten
        self.config_thread = config()
        self.config_thread.finished.connect(self.fadeOUT)
        self.config_thread.start()
```

Thanks for your help eyllanesc :)